# User apache can't access files it owns

Tags: php, linux, apache

Ok, I am having issues with a script I am trying to run.  I am trying to move file A from `/mount/images/sync` to `/mount/images/logos`.  Both of these folders are owned by apache:root.  However, when I try to move them, it won't create the subdirectories of `/mount/images/logos`.

When I check to see who I'm logged in as when running the script, it IS apache.

Not sure where to look to figure out what is going on.  Any help would be great, and please, ask me any questions so I can give you the information you need.  Not sure where to start.

EDIT EDIT EDIT

I should mention that `mount/images/logos` is a symbolic link pointing back to another folder, and the source folder is a mount point.

Mount Information:

`mount "//192.168.1.10/design1" /home/opmasan/design1 -o ip=192.168.1.10,username=***,password=***,uid=48`

Comment: who owns the `.` entry?

Comment: @DevZer0 what do you mean by `.` entry?

Comment: Permissions set to 770?

Comment: Permissions are set to 755, and I cannot modify the permissions for whatever reason, even when logged in as root.

Comment: who owns /mount/images/logos and what permissions on the `.` entry when u do a ls

Comment: when u say /mount is this a nfs mount?

Comment: Yes, /mount is a nfs mount from a windows location.  /mount/images/logos is owned by apache

Comment: What's the mask on the mount?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid not sure what you mean.  I will post the code I use to mount the folder above.

Comment: Bump on this... No help at all?  @BurhanKhalid, you seem to know what I am trying to do, do you have a solution at all?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add...

> ```
> Options +FollowSymlinks
> ```

... to the  section for /mount/images in your Apache configuration.

Check the [Options Directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) for more info.

Comment: `FollowSymlinks` was already on prior to this.  However, I did add it to my `httpd.conf` file under the `</Directory>`, and it did not make a difference.

Comment: The problem is copying files at the shell, not browsing files from Apache.  It just so happens that the files are owned by the same user account that is used to run Apache.  Adding/modifying this will not make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try to switch selinux to permissive mode.

Comment: SElinux is currently disabled.